# Quais são as diferenças entre implementação de mapas por hashes ou árvores?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, hash, árvore-binária

Qual a vantagem da implementação de mapas por tabela *hash* ao invés da árvore binaria?

Comment: Aqui tem um link que acredito vai te ajudar: [Listas, árvores e tabela hash](ftp://ftp.dca.fee.unicamp.br/pub/docs/ia875/lth.pdf)

Comment: Acho que compreendi o que estava procurando,vê se minha lógica tem sentido e se tiver coloque como resposta para colocar como solucionado já que sem sua ajuda não teria conseguido.

Comment: Resposta :É mais adequado a implementação da tabela Hash  em um cenario quando se tem um grande volume de dados,sendo assim sua grande vantagem é o desempenho,enquanto a  busca binária tem complexidade $ O(\log N)$  , o tempo de busca na tabela hash é praticamente independente do número de chaves armazenadas na tabela, ou seja, tem complexidade temporal $ O(1)$.
Resumindo:
Na tabela Hash seu desempenho não está relacionado com o sua quantidade de dados,ou seja para buscas com grande volume de dados é mais adequado sua utilização.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dúvida deveria ser mais ao contrário.

Se você precisa que os dados sejam classificados você precisa da árvore binária. Se precisa de ordem, precisa de um *array*, ou algum truque com a árvore binária (ou não). Se pode desprezar ordem ou classificação então a tabela de espalhamento pode ser útil.

A tabela de espalhamento possui complexidade O(1), ou seja, é constante não importa o volume de dados. É como se fosse o tempo de acesso de um *array* pelo seu índice. Não o mesmo tempo porque o *hash* precisa calcular o *bucket* onde o dado está antes de acessar.

A árvore binária tem complexidade O(log n) que em muitos casos é próximo de constante. De fato por não ter que calcular com baixo volume de dados é possível que ele seja mais rápido que *hash*, mesmo que log n dê algo maior que 1. Em grandes volumes será mais lento, mas não é uma diferença tão grande assim. Para ter uma ideia 1 bilhão de elementos pode ser acessado em apenas 30 passos. Apesar do volume influenciar o tempo de acesso, é irrisório, e em alguns casos não faz diferença.