# Pra que serve o objeto Map em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, map

Essa também parece ser uma outra novidade do JavaScript: o objeto `Map`.

Diferentemente do [Set](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313890/pra-que-serve-o-objeto-set-do-javascript), que eu já faço ideia de como funciona e vi em outras linguagens, o `Map` é algo que não cheguei a ver em nenhuma linguagem que trabalhei.

- Para que serve o objeto `Map`?
- O que diferencia ele de um `Object` comum?
- Quando devo utilizar o `Map`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

São quase idênticos no geral, um [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) é um mapa, mas não exatamente a estrutura `Map` disponível, portanto há detalhes de implementação que os diferencia, mas servem para mesma coisa.

De acordo com a [página da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as diferenças são:

- As chaves de um `Object` são `Strings` e [`Symbols`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300099/), mas no `Map` podem ser qualquer valor, incluindo funções, objetos e qualquer primitivo.
- As chaves no mapa são [ordenadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101) enquanto as chaves adicionadas ao objeto não são. Assim, quando iterar sobre ele, um objeto `Map` retorna chaves em ordem de inserção.
- Você pode obter o tamanho de um mapa facilmente com a propriedade `size`, enquanto o número de propriedades em um objeto deve ser determinado manualmente.
- Um mapa é um iterável e pode, portanto, ser diretamente iterado, enquanto iterar sobre um objeto requer a obtenção de suas chaves de alguma forma e iterar sobre elas, ainda que tenha função que ajude nisto, não é direto.
- Um `Object` tem um protótipo, portanto, há chaves padrões no mapa que podem colidir com suas chaves, se você não for cuidadoso. A partir do ES5, isso pode ser ignorado usando `map = Object.create(null)`, mas isso raramente é feito.
- Um `Map` pode ter um melhor desempenho em cenários que envolvam adição e remoção frequente de pares de chaves.

Geralmente é uma questão semântica. Para algo que se pareça mais com um objeto simples use `Object`, quando tem uma coleção de dados use um `Map`, ou outra estrutura que faça mais sentido.

Aparentemente, mas sem ser certeza, `Object` tem [complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101) constante e [`Map` tem complexidade logarítmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179852/101). Provavelmente o que respondi em [Quais são as diferenças entre implementação de mapas por hashes ou árvores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313513/101).

Digo aparentemente porque não há nada na [especificação](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-map-objects), que alias é muito ruim, não diz nada sobre outras garantias que pode, em tese ser igual as outras estruturas que também não exigem certas garantias, como ordenação. Não há nada canônico, apenas fortes indícios que as complexidades são estas.

> Map objects are collections of key/value pairs where both the keys and values may be arbitrary ECMAScript language values. A distinct key value may only occur in one key/value pair within the Map’s collection. Distinct key values are discriminated using the SameValueZero comparison algorithm.
>
> Map object must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection. The data structures used in this Map objects specification is only intended to describe the required observable semantics of Map objects. It is not intended to be a viable implementation model.

[image: Gráfico BigO]

[Veja exemplos](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373) (mas o texto aparentemente tem coisas erradas).

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264887/101). [Também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101). E [como é em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271621/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma coisa que me incomoda profundamente no `Map` é que não podemos informar uma função de hash a ser usada internamente. É preciso calcular explicitamente o hash caso não se queira usar o design padrão. Torna-se muito menos conveniente e menos expressivo.